# linked list operator overloading issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

i tried to build up my own linked list class and got a problem with the `= operator overloading.` as far as i know, we should use const parameter when overloading the assignment operator, say using `linked_list<T>& operator=( const linked_list<T>& a)`. however, the complier gave me errors unless i put `linked_list<T>&` a instead. the complier would stop at 
`if(this->head==a.front())`, giving me Error

```
11  error C2662: 'linked_list<T>::front' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const linked_list<T>' to 'linked_list<T> &'
```

below are the details.

```
#ifndef _LINKED_LIST_H_
#define _LINKED_LIST_H_
template <class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node<T>* next;
};
template <class T>
class linked_list
{
   private:
    node<T>* head;
   public:
    linked_list<T>();
    linked_list<T>(const linked_list<T>& a);
    ~linked_list<T>();
    linked_list<T>& operator=(const linked_list<T>& a);
    bool isEmpty();
    int size() const;
    void insert_front(T a);
    void insert_end(T a);
    void erase_end();
    void erase_front();
    void print() const;
    void erase(node<T>* a);
    node<T>*& front()
    {
        node<T>* ptr = new node<T>;
        ptr = head;
        return ptr;
    }
    void setFront(node<T>* a);
};
#endif
template <class T>
linked_list<T>& linked_list<T>::operator=(const linked_list<T>& a)
{
    if (this->head == a.front())  // the error mentioned happened here. however,
                                  // if no const in the parameter, it would be
                                  // no error
    {
        return *this;
    }
    while (head != nullptr) erase_front();
    node<T>* copy;
    copy = a.front();
    while (copy->next != nullptr)
    {
        insert_end(copy->data);
        copy = copy->next;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

anybody can help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an accessor returns a reference to an owned structure, it's usually a good idea to implement two versions: One which is non-const and returns a non-const reference, and one which is const and returns a const reference. That way it can be used in both mutating and non-mutating contexts. `front()` would be a good candidate for this.

Though a side note -- you probably don't want to expose your `node`s in the public `linked_list` interface, particularly non-const references to them. That's the sort of thing to encapsulate entirely in the class.

Comment: thx for ur help. problem solved and can you explain more on the side note? how do i encapsulate entirely in the class? i tried to put struct definition in the class and then i got lots of errors...

Comment: He means that you essentially want to store items of type `T` in a list. You don't care, as an external consumer, that the list needs an internal "shim" such as that `node` struct. Hence, `front()` should return `T&`, and not `node<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `front()` is not a const member function, and you're trying to call it on a const instance.

Comment: problem solved. now i have both node<T>*& front() & node<T>*& front() const, two methods! thanks lol!